# Problema para contar los días hasta la fecha C

Tags: c

Tengo un problema en la función "fecha".

El enunciado me pide que dado un dia, mes y año, devuelva los días que pasaron de ese año, por ejemplo, el 3 de marzo sería 31 dias de enero + 28 dias de febrero + 3 días de marzo.

El problema es que la función no está devolviendo la cantidad de días que debería.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bis(int ano);
int fecha(int dia, int mes);


int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    int cardinal, bisiesto;
    printf("\n\nIntroduzca una fecha en formato aa(dia), bb(mes), cccc(ano): \n\n");
    scanf("%i %i %i",&a, &b, &c);
    bisiesto = bis(c);
    cardinal = fecha(a,b);
    printf("\n\n%i\n\n", cardinal);

}

int bis(int ano) {

    int c;
    if (ano%4==0 && ano%100!=0) {
        c = 1;
    }
    else if (ano%400==0){
        c = 1;
    }
    else {
        c = 0;
    }

    return c;

}


int fecha(int dia, int mes) {

    int v[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int total = 0;
    int dias_mes = 0;
    int m;
    for (m=1; m<=mes; m++) {
        if (m==1) {
            total = dia;
        }
        else {
            dias_mes = dias_mes + v[m];
            total = dia + dias_mes;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿La función no devuelve la cantidad de días correcta?

Comment: Gracias. Sí, en enero y febrero me devuelve la cantidad correcta, pero cuando paso al tercer mes me suma dos días de mas en todos los meses.

Answer (score 1):

En el for sumas el día varias veces, excepto en el mes de enero.

```
total = dia + dias_mes;
```

Esa línea deberías moverla afuera del ciclo.

Se supone que deberías sumar los meses que ya pasaron. Pero como la condición del for es `m <= mes` también cuentas el mes que no pasó.

Por ejemplo, si `mes` es 3, la suma que está haciendo es `31 + 28 + 31`.

Entonces la condición que buscas es `m < mes`.

El código te quedaría así:

```
int fecha(int dia, int mes) {

    int v[] = { 0, 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int total = dia;
    
    for (int m = 1; m < mes; m++) {
        total += v[m];
    }

    return total;
}
```